Overflow on CSS not working for salesforce lightning-record-picker component
I have a record picker component that is put inside a table. When the user starts typing the component pulls in matching values to select from. The list that shows up when the users enters is partly covered by the elements beneath it. Now how do I make the list show up all values, which means this component should overlay on top of other elements.
Here is my HTML
<div class="table_component slds-p-around_medium" role="region" tabindex="0">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select Parts</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-layout class="slds-p-around_small" multiple-rows="true">
                            <lightning-layout-item size="12">
                                    <!-- <div class="overflow-on-top"> -->
                                    <lightning-record-picker placeholder="Search Parts" variant="label-hidden"
                                        label="Select Part" object-api-name="Product2" matching-info={matchingInfo}
                                        display-info={displayInfo} filter={filter}
                                        onchange={handlePartPicker}></lightning-record-picker>
                                </div>
                                <lightning-layout class="slds-m-top_small">
                                    <lightning-layout-item size="4">
                                        <lightning-input placeholder="Quantity" variant="label-hidden" type="number"
                                            min="1" max="9999" name="quantity"
                                            onchange={handleQuantityInputChange}></lightning-input>
                                    </lightning-layout-item>
                                    <lightning-layout-item size="4">
                                        <lightning-input class="slds-p-left_x-small" placeholder="Unit Price"
                                            variant="label-hidden" type="currency" min="1" max="9999" name="unitPrice"
                                            onchange={handleUnitPriceInputChange}></lightning-input>
                                    </lightning-layout-item>
                                    <lightning-layout-item size="4">
                                        <div class="slds-float_right">
                                            <lightning-button label="Add Part" variant="brand"
                                                onclick={handleAddPart}></lightning-button>
                                        </div>
                                    </lightning-layout-item>
                                </lightning-layout>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

Here is the CSS -
.table_component {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.table_component table {
    border: 1px solid #dededf;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: left;
}

.table_component caption {
    caption-side: top;
    text-align: left;
}

.table_component th {
    border: 1px solid #dededf;
    background-color: #eceff1;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
}

.table_component td {
    border: 1px solid #dededf;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
}

.custom-row {
    height: 5px; /* Adjust this value to change the height of the rows */
}

.picker-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}

.overflow-on-top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999; /* Adjust this value to change the stack order */
}

